# Use the metal in a metal core PCB as the GND layer

Tags: pcb-layers

As I understand in a metal core PCB there's a copper layer, thermally conductive dielectric layer and then the metal layer for the heat dissipation. Can vias come to this metal layer so that it can act as the GND layer in a PCB design?

Comment: Yes they can. I believe the metal layer can also have clearance holes for vias between top and bottom copper layers.

Comment: Best to ask your board house for direction before doing a design

Comment: I was thinking of only one copper layer design with the metal layer used as only GND. Anyone with experience doing such a design?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically not. By default, via enable the connection between the layers, but technologically they must be protected against contact of the vias with the metal core, because then it would cause a short circuit on the board (not every vias you want to connect with a metal core).

But theoretically, you can order a PCB with mounting holes through all layers (copper, insulator and metal core) and then you could connect such layers with, for example, screws or maybe some solder.

[image]

[Source](https://www.pcbway.com/pcb_prototype/Metal_core_PCBs.html)

But it's still best to ask a specific PCB supplier, because what will be impossible for one, for technologically expensive ones, it is possible to implement.